# Measure speed between two exact sites

Tags: linux, windows, networking, performance-testing

I would really like to measure connection speed between two exact sites. Naturally one of the sites is our site. Somehow I need to prove that not our internet connection is flaky, but that a site at the other end, is overcrowded.

At our end I have windows and linux machines available for this.

I imagine I would run a script at certain times of day which - for example - tries to download an image from that site and try to measure download time. Then put the download time into a database then create a graph from the records in the database. (I know that this is really simple and not sophisticated enough, but hence my question)

I need help on the time measurement.

The felt speed differences are big, sometimes the application works flawlessly, but sometimes we get timed out errors.
Now I use speedtest to check if our internet connection is OK, but this does not show that the site that is not working is slow, and now I can't provide hard numbers to assist my situation.
Maybe it is worth mentioning that the application we try to use at the other end is java based.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in Linux:

Use `wget` to download whatever URL you think represents your sites best. Parse the output into a file (`sed`, `awk`), use `crontab` to trigger the download multiple times.

```
wget www.google.com
...
2014-02-24 22:03:09 (1.26 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [11251]
```